# Traditional(?) Italian(?) accordion instrumental waltz

Tags: identify-this-song, song-title, unknown-composer

It's an Italian song and I think it's folkloric (and maybe not).

It hasn't any lyrics.

You can watch it from this Youtube video.

The poster of the video credits it to Yasushi Akutagawa - *School of Love* 1981, but I think it must be much older than that. Katsuhisa Hattori is one of the composers of that Japanese anime; he is Japanese himself. He himself has borrowed this music from the original Italian song. I want to know the Italian name of the song and also, its Italian composer.

The accordionist in that Youtube video is Italian and his name is Mario Levetto. But I doubt he is the original composer.

Answer (score 3):

This is the opening and ending theme of ["بچه‌های مدرسه والت" / "Bachehaye Madrese Walt"](https://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A8%DA%86%D9%87%E2%80%8C%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C_%D9%85%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%B3%D9%87_%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA) ("Walt School Kids"), formerly titled "مدرسه عشق: قصهٔ دل" ("School of Love: the Story of Heart"). This anime is the Iranian version of [愛の学校クオレ物語 / Ai no Gakko Cuore Monogatari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ai_no_Gakko_Cuore_Monogatari), a 1981 Japanese anime based on Edmondo de Amicis's 1886 novel ["Cuore, Libro per i Ragazzi"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_(novel)).

The soundtrack of the Iranian version is different from the original Japanese soundtrack. Actually, it is borrowed from the fourth episode, where street musicians [are shown playing this Walz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUYpGeXqqyE&t=1204s) and Enrico's parents are dancing on it. If I understand correctly (the Google translation of) what is written on the [Farsi Wikipedia page](https://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A8%DA%86%D9%87%E2%80%8C%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C_%D9%85%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%B3%D9%87_%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA), this sequence was censored by the Iranian TV but this accordion music was kept as the opening/ending soundtrack. For those who can read Farsi (I can't), more details are given in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DVil_E9ALrY).

According to [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0296297/soundtrack), the original opening and ending songs were composed by [Yasushi Akutagawa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yasushi_Akutagawa) and arranged by [Katsuhisa Hattori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katsuhisa_Hattori). They were great composers that were perfectly able to compose such a waltz for accordion. Do you have any evidence other than the video that this is an older song, and was not composed by them? **The video is misleading. If you watch carefully, the accordion player is not playing what we are hearing.**

You can find the downloadable music score and MIDI file here: https://musescore.com/user/33055012/scores/6494225
(FWIW credited composer is Katsuhisa Hattori but that page is not a solid reference)

You can also listen to a good quality (alternate) version of the song [on soundcloud](https://soundcloud.com/r-skandari/bachehayemadresevaalt).

Comment: Thank you for your effort to answer my question friend. But: 1) Katsuhisa Hattori is one of the composers of that Japanese anime; he is Japanese himself. He himself has borrowed this music from the original Italian song. I want to know the Italian name of the song and also, its Italian composer. 2) As you said, Ai no Gakko Cuore Monogatari was produced in 1981. But the youtube video I've posted is surely before that year (old filming). 3) The accordionist in that Youtube video is Italian and his name is Mario Levetto. But I doubt he is the original composer.

Comment: Also, there's writing on the wall of the studio in that youtube video: "Fisarmoniche Alla Ribalta". I don't know if it helps but after I searched for it on the internet, I found many accordion songs; but none of them was that particular one.

Comment: @aminabzz What you wrote here is very interesting and should be part of your question. My comments: 1) Katsuhisa Hattori as borrowed this music from the original Italian song => Do you have any evidence for this (other than the video)? Yes, this is possible, and even probable because playing accordion that way is not easy (I used to play accordion myself) and this suggests the music is played by a true accordionist, but that doesn't mean Katsuhisa Hattori didn't compose it. 2) and 3) This YT video is misleading. If you watch carefully, the accordion player is not playing what we are hearing.